# How to find criterion that best separates two populations in a dataset?

Tags: optimization, data-analysis, python

I have a dataset of two identified populations that contains various parameters for each data point. I would like to find the best criterion, i.e. the relation between e.g. three of those parameters, that best separates those two populations.

Imagine for example that we look at the human population and we would like to find the best relation between parameters such as hight, age and weight to separate men from women.

I would like to do this in Python, but I don't know the correct keywords. I'm pretty sure this is a common optimization problem, so there likely already exists a library out there that can do it.

Comment: You might have a better chance in the data science SE , that is how the cool kids deal with questions like these , these a days

Comment: Haha ok, fair enough! Do you think it's ok to simply ask the same question there as well?

Answer (score 1):

Populations are usually normally distributed.
Therefore, I'd consider the EM algorithm for a mixture of Gaussians.

See: Mitzenmacher and Upfal: Probability and Computing, Cambridge Univ. Press, 2nd edition, 2017 (section 9.7).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip! I don't have that book though, but maybe I find it somewhere else.